# "error launching remote program: device locked out" xcode 4.2.1 and ipad 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm getting this error when trying to build a project and run it on iPad iOS 5.0.1:

```
error launching remote program: device locked out
```

Also, in the Organizer I'm getting this message:

```
Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version.
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try turning off the passcode protection on your iPad, it might work then... what xcode version are you using??
"Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" is just a warning. wont do much harm

Comment: what is it passcode protection?
i'm using xcode version 4.2.1. the latest.

Comment: ur device has password protection enabled .. turn it off in settings

Comment: If you don't want to turn off passcode protection, make sure your device is unlocked before you use Xcode to build

Answer (score 0):

try to delete all apps in your device in setting>Management> there will be your developer id .make it untrust and then disconnect your device and again connect .it will ask you for trust click on trust and try installing your app on your device .this time it will be installed easily.